# solution explorer view of typescript and output javascript files

Tags: typescript

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with typescript and web essentials 2012 plugin. 
If you add a new typescript file by right clicking solution explorer > Add New Item > selecting typescript file...eg file1.ts
Visual Studio generates the file1.js and file1.min.js as well. In solution explorer, they appear neatly under the file1.ts file root.
If you do 'Add Existing item' eg file2.ts, you don't get that neat looking appearance where the generated file2.js appears under the file2.ts name.

Why is that? and what setting do I need to change to make visual studio make all the generated js file appear under the ts file root.

i hope i'm making sense.

btw This has always been the case ever since the first typescript plugin release
thanks
kashim

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the desired effect, you'll need to hack about in the project file. You'll notice that the correctly nested files look like this:

```
<Content Include="app.js">
  <DependentUpon>app.ts</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<Content Include="app.min.js">
  <DependentUpon>app.ts</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

Whereas you probably currently have `Content` elements for each file without the `DependentUpon` element inside.

Changing the project file to match this example will nest the items for you.

Comment: @user2018413 You can also just delete the `js` and `map` files, then recompile - they should reappear correctly nested.

Comment: @JcFx Thanks but that didn't work for me. I created a simple typescript project and added an existing typescript file (a very simple one) from another project. I made sure the typescript file's property 'BuildAction' was "TypeScriptCompile". A rebuild generated the javascript file but there was no nested view in solution explorer. After unloading the project and inspecting the project file, I can see the <DependentUpon> element was not generated. thanks any way. regards kashim

Comment: @SteveFenton Yes. I think OP has WE (according to first line of post).

Comment: @user2018413 That's a pity. It works all the time for me but we must have some variation in setup.

Answer (score 3):

There's a little VS plugin, called **NestIn** which does the trick without directly editing the project file (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d6ef0ce-2bef-4a82-9a84-7718caa5bb45). No settings, no configs, just right-click on the two+ files and nest them in. The only thing you'd need is to specify which is the root. And, of course, you can un-nest the nested files if you wish so.

Another one, by Mads Kristensen, **File Nesting**, works only for Visual Studio  2013 & 2015. So, if you plan to upgrade to higher VS version you may give it a try too.

Comment: Thanks for the lead on **File Nesting** extension -- big help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small regEx that does this job!

Unload your project in the Solution Explorer, then right click and select "Edit"

In the file, run a Search & Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>) with RegEx (the star symbol enable) and replace:

`<Content Include="(.*)\\([^\\]*).js" />`

with

`<Content Include="$1\$2.js"><DependentUpon>$2.ts</DependentUpon></Content>`

Now save the file and reload the project.