# How to turn off javascript file nesting in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 when I create a new js file with the same name and in the same folder as an html file, it will be nested under it:

[image]

And I just can't turn off this nesting in `Tools / Options`, but maybe it only eluded me. I've tried the vs extension described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358070/solution-explorer-view-of-typescript-and-output-javascript-files). But when I click on `File Nesting / Un-nest item` nothing happens, it stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extension you do not want to nest in the following file:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\.filenesting.JSON`

I'm on:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.3.4